# Django 1.11 - is there a way to combine fields from models.Model to auth.models?

Tags: django, admin, models

What I aim to achieve in the end is to combine the list of **all** users (from auth.models) with a DateTimeField from another model (model.Model). What's the best way of doing this?

My code:

**survey/models/response.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Response(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
```

In admin.py, I can create a custom user class which lists all of the registered users' usernames like so:

**survey/admin.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

admin.site.unregister(User)

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username',)

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Essentially I want extend **UserAdmin** as *list_display = ('username', **'created'**)* - with *username* coming from *auth.models* and *created* coming from *models.Model*.

At the moment I can create a class in admin.py that shows me a list of all the users *who have submitted* a Response. The issue is that if you have 200 users, it is more useful to see who *hasn't* submitted from a list of all users than only listing the users who have submitted a Response.

Comment: If you a user has multiple response objects how are you expecting to show it in the list display of the admin page?

Comment: I just want to display the **latest** response object within UserAdmin. I can use inlines to create a list of users who responded per Response object or a list of Responses per User object. I don't have a problem with that. I can also produce a csv of every User and every Response if need be. This is more for creating a simple UI that you can filter to determine who still needs to respond within the last period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function to fetch relevant data for you to show in the admin listing page.

In your admin.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

admin.site.unregister(User)

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'latest_response')

    def latest_response(self, obj):
        return obj.response_set.latest('created')  # Or any other logic you want to apply here to return a string or boolean that can be shown on the admin

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: Amazing, that's exactly what I needed. Work perfectly. I was just about to try extending the user model through the abstractUser model. Thanks!

Comment: If you are setting up a new project, I highly recommend extending the AbstractUser model to create your own user (since this can be done only in the beginning of a project). This will allow you to easily add more columns(fields) to the user model

Comment: I will be doing exactly that when I move this into production, but right now it's a proof of concept and I don't want to purge my database. This does what I need for now and is actually a very good concept to understand. Thanks again.